# How can I access `react-redux` store from child components when I initially assign it in `<Provider>`?>

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So, as far as I know `<Provider store={ store }></Provider>` will make store reference available throughout all children.

How can I retrieve the `store` value in my children element?

Also where are the documentation for React Redux, specifically for `<Provider>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use react-redux `connect` function https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md to connect your state(store) to your component. `mapStateToProps` will then map your store values to props of that component.

Comment: Any other example? Honestly, it is not clear what and how I can properly set `connect()`.

Comment: Nevermind! I solve it thanks to you. Although, I hoped the documentation for React Redux is a little bit clearer.

Comment: @notalentgeek : If you've got suggestions for improving our docs, please file an issue (or even better, a PR to help improve them)!.  Also, you may be interested in the [Redux Tutorials](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/redux-tutorials.md) section of my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links).  I can specifically recommend these: https://daveceddia.com/how-does-redux-work/ , http://jakesidsmith.com/blog/post/2017-11-18-redux-and-react-an-introduction/ .